# htaccess rewrite key/value pair params in url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I know this is very common question but I can't seem find any solution regarding in my problem. The folder structure looks like this:

```
- rootProject
  - subfolder
    * .htaccess
    * index.php
```

Normal url params: `http://website.com/subfolder/?dynamicKey=dynamicValue`.
But What I want to achieve is like this: `http://website.com/subfolder/dynamicKey/dynamicValue`

But I failed to do that, I can only retrieve the `dynamicKey`.

Here is my current `htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Maybe `RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?$1=$2 [NC,QSA,L]`?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Ar Rakin. Here is the solution.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?$1=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples and attempted code, please try following htaccess rules. We need to add conditional checks before rewrite rules else later it will affect your existing pages also.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
##Added conditions if non-existing pages requested then only perform rewrite.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?$1 [NC,QSA,L]

##Added conditions if non-existing pages requested then only perform rewrite.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?$1=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

***NOTE:*** your used regex `[a-z]` will only match small letters in uri, in case it needed to check any alphabets(capital OR small) then change FROM `[a-z]` TO `[a-zA-Z]` in above rules also.

Comment: There is one more point here, please keep your htaccess and index.php files in same level folder too.